# set position of infowindow android google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, infowindow

I have used custom **infowindow** when marker is clicked.

But it is showing window at default location.

i.e. on top of marker.

But, I want **infowindow** to get overlapped on marker.

How can set position for infowindow??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this is not currently possible in `Google Map API V2`, I think that there is an open issue as for for this kind of task, I just can find it at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer.
[Another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943568/android-google-map-infowindow-anchor-point-after-marker-rotation)
SetInfoWindowAnchor method is really what you need.